# GSON an Java Throwable

Tags: java, exception, gson

I have an object that contains a piece of data and associated exception.

```
Public class MyBean{
  Private String data;
  Private Exception problem;
.
.
.
}
```

When I try to *GSON.toJSON(object)* it gives me a **circular references** error complaining about the "problem" field.

Is there a way to for GSON to handle such objects ?

Comment: I experienced the same problem when trying to serialize an object with an org.apache.log4j.Logger field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gson does indeed complain about a circular reference error when attempting to serialize a data structure as described in the original question.

The following example demonstrates this point.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.data = "some data";
    bean.problem = new RuntimeException("Ack!");

    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(bean));
  }
}

class MyBean
{
  public String data;
  public Exception problem;
}
```

This example results in the following exception and message from Gson.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: circular reference error
  Offending field: cause

  Offending object: preserveType: false, type: class java.lang.Throwable, obj: java.lang.RuntimeException: Ack!
    at com.google.gson.CircularReferenceException.createDetailedException(CircularReferenceException.java:43)
    at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitObjectField(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:117)
...
```

Gson similarly chokes when attempting something as simple as the following.

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(new RuntimeException("Ack!")));
```

Gson does not currently have a configuration available to simply resolve this problem.  I recommend logging an issue at http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/list.

If an object with an `Exception` reference must be serialized and if Gson must be used, then custom serialization processing for the `Exception` reference must be implemented.  Following is one such example.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.data = "some data";
    bean.problem = new RuntimeException("Ack!");

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Exception.class, new ExceptionSerializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(bean));
  }
}

class ExceptionSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Exception>
{
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Exception src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
  {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.add("cause", new JsonPrimitive(String.valueOf(src.getCause())));
    jsonObject.add("message", new JsonPrimitive(src.getMessage()));
    return jsonObject;
  }
}

class MyBean
{
  public String data;
  public Exception problem;
}
```

**output:**

```
{"data":"some data","problem":{"cause":"null","message":"Ack!"}}
```

---

For what it's worth, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) does not similarly choke when attempting to serialize the same data structure.  Jackson serializes a `MyBean` instance to JSON as follows.

```
{
  "data":"some data",
  "problem":
  {
    "cause":null,
    "message":"Ack!",
    "localizedMessage":"Ack!",
    "stackTrace":
    [
      {
        "className":"com.stackoverflow.q8151082.JacksonFoo",
        "fileName":"JacksonFoo.java",
        "lineNumber":11,
        "methodName":"main",
        "nativeMethod":false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for reference, here is a link to the respective Gson issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=469 Please star the issue so that it gets more attention.

Comment: I suggest using registerTypeHierarchyAdapter instead of registerTypeAdapter since you probably want to use the custom serializer for all subtypes of Exception.

Comment: This has been fixed in Gson v2.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I know that it's not the answer to the specific question (that was answered correctly before more than 2 years)
But:

for those who get this exception in other cases:

**this error happens while trying to parse complicated field that gson doesn't know to parse.**

if you need this field in your class, but not for parsing purpose and you want to exclude it from the gson parsing, you can:

- **add the `@Expose` annotation to all the fields that you want to parse**,(something like `@Expose private Long id;`)
- **declare the Gson object like this:**

  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

that's what helped me

Answer (score 0):

GSON can handle other custom classes as attributes of your first class, but are you using it that way ?

```
gson.fromJson(yourResponse,MyBean.class)
```

and is Exception one of your custom class? Maybe if can be in conflict with java.lang.Exception.

Comment: the Exception is a held within the bean is a plain java.lang.Exception. it is complaining about the Exception field itself.

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same problem in Gson version 2.2.2. In Gson version 2.6.1 I do not see this problem.