# GSON.toJson(new RuntimeException()) throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception, gson

My application was throwing StackOverflowError. Found out that our application logs the Exception in form of JSON and had below code.

```
GSON.toJson(object) //here object can be my application exception or any runtime exception
```

To my surprise it GSON.toJson throws StackOverflowError.

Tried below setup  to verify:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson GSON = new Gson();
    GSON.toJson(new NullPointerException());
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:519)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:387)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:300)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:190)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
```

Can someone tell why I can't get JSON of any exception?

NOTE: This happens in only our application

Comment: This is due to circular reference, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8199566/2257172

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON an Java Throwable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151082/gson-an-java-throwable)

Comment: Thanks I did not see the post. Anyway I was not getting this error in my new project, found out in Gson 2.6.1 this error doesn't pop. I was using 2.2.2 earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to version Gson 2.6.1 solved the problem